# how to re-trigger Jenkins job that are failed due to timeout?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

how to re-trigger jenkins jobs with command line that has the *Timeout* in the console message since last hour/ week ?

These are my Jenkins console output of some of the Jenkins Jobs

```
Timeout has been exceeded
Finished: ABORTED
```

**Original Pipeline**

```
stage('Test') {
    options {
        timeout(time: 45, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
    steps {
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_1; /home/jenkins/tests/test_1.sh'
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_2; /home/jenkins/tests/test_2.sh'
    }
}
```

**Modification for retry**

```
stage('Test') {
    options {
        timeout(time: 45, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
    try {
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_1; /home/jenkins/tests/test_1.sh'
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_2; /home/jenkins/tests/test_2.sh'
    } catch(error) {
      retry(2) {
        input "Timeout has been exceeded"
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_1; /home/jenkins/tests/test_1.sh'
        sh label: '', script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE}/logs/test_2; /home/jenkins/tests/test_2.sh'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [retry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) directive to achieve the same.

Comment: edited the question, can you check if the modified retry code is ok or there are other better ways to do it

Comment: Have you tried it by implementing the same in pipeline script ?